# How to get user data in form in Symfony 1.2?

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using Symfony 1.2 in a standard Propel form class.

```
public function configure()
{
    $this->setWidgets(array( 
'graduate_job_title' => new sfWidgetFormInput( array(), array( 'maxlength' => 80, 'size' => 30, 'value' => '' ) )
    ));
    //etc
}
```

However, I want the value of this field to come from the user information, which I'd normally access using `$this->getUser()->getAttribute( '...' )`. However, this doesn't seem to work in the form.

What should I be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Does that work?</strike>

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('...');
```

**// Edit** : See cirpo's recommandation on the use of sfContext instead.

Answer (score 14):

It's a very bad idea to rely on the sfContext instance.
It's better to pass what you need during sfForm initialization in the options array parameter.

http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfForm

__contruct method

for example in your action:

```
$form = new myForm(null, 
                   array('attributeFoo' => 
                         $this->getUser()->getAttribute('attributeFoo'));
```

and then retrieve the value inside the form class:

> $this->getOption('attributeFoo');

cirpo

Comment: What if you are using a plugin like sfDoctrineGuard which autogenerates the forms? I am not directly creating the forms in my own classes.

Comment: It was what I was looking for. Thanks!
In my case it work with Symfony 1.4

Answer (score 1):

If someone need the same in admin (backend) here is a solution:
http://blog.nevalon.de/en/wie-nutze-ich-die-rechteverwaltung-in-symfony-admin-generator-formularen-20100729

Answer (score -1):

In Symfony 1.4, object **$sf_user**